# Random number formula returns same number batch

Tags: random, batch-file, cmd

i am trying to make a random number between 1 and a variable, this variable will change each time the program runs. i am using this so far:
SET /A result=%random%*%var%/32768+1

but everytime i re-run the batch file it returns the same number, do people know what is going on?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You ought to add a tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
set /a result=(%random% %% %var%) + 1
```

Comment: On my system %random% just increases over time and hence is not particularly random. If you expect very different results every time you run then using modulo is going to produce more random looking results.

Comment: No. `%random%` have a certain distribution that is preserved via `%random%*var/32768`. Modulo operator alter this distribution and create a different one that is "less random" than the original.

Comment: When I use %random% in a batch file and run it two or 3 times I just get a slightly higher number each time. I am guessing this is something to do with how %random% is generated. The reason I suggested using modulo is that even a small change in %random% will result in a completely different output. I assumed that modulo was not quite as random as the proper method but I believe it shouldn't matter for small %var%'s.  

In any case, both user2035296's and your code produced the same number each time I ran it. My code works provided you can tolerate a slightly imperfect distribution of numbers.

Comment: I just wrote a Batch file that show `%random%` in three lines; I double click on it and get this result: `3012 23343 8426`. I then run it again and get this result: `17735 12172 8635`. If you get no really random results with %random%, perhaps there is a problem with your system...

Comment: Writing it 3 times in the same batch file works fine. The problem comes when I run one batch file 3 times in rapid succession.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to enclose `var` in percent signs in `SET /A` command; this form should solve all problems related to normal expansion inside/outside of blocks:

```
SET /A result=%random%*var/32768+1
```

However, if previous command is *inside* a block, you should change it for this one (and enable Delayed Expansion):

```
SET /A result=!random!*var/32768+1
```

If previous solution still don't works, I could bet that you are defining a variable called `random`! This prevent that `%random%` be created internally and always return the value that *you* assigned to it.

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

IMO you have to use delayed expansion in a `for` or `if` code block.

Comment: its not in a for or if block, and after i changed it to delayed expansion it still didn't work